# Is there a way to make a function that's available to all Activities?

Tags: android, function, android-activity, global, restart

I have a set of commands that I want my app to run when it's restarted, regardless of what activity it's on. I know I need to put an `onRestart()` into every one.

Since it's the same set of commands regardless of what activity it's on, is there a way I could have them all refer to a single function for that?  It seems like that would be better then having to copy paste the commands into each `onRestart()` handler. It will be a lot less work if I need to change the set of commands too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options, depending on the code.

You can put it in a helper class as a static function: `public static void doWork() { .. }`  This should work, unless whatever you are doing depends on being in the activity.  You can generally just pass it what it needs though, like the `Context`.

Or, you could extend `Activity` with your own class, `MyActivity` and place the work in that `onResume`.  Then extend `MyActivity` for each of your real activities.  They will now automatically do that work when you call `super.onResume()`.  This works well as long as you really want to do the same thing in every activity, and don't use a lot of specialized activities like `ListActivity`.

Edit:

```
public class MyHelper {

  public static void doWork() {
    // do your work here
  }

}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MyHelper.doWork();
  }
}
```

A search for "static method" will provide more details.

Comment: +1 I'd use the class with `static` methods approach myself as I find it easier to maintain.  Even if you don't use any specialised `Activities` right now, if you add any in the future you may end up with a big code refactor.

Comment: that sounds good. I like the " helper class as a static function" approach as there are some situaions that I don't want it to do those steps on certian screens, and I already know how to test for those situations so I could put in an if statement in the on resume to to call the helper if that situation isn't present. but how do I implement the helper? can you put in an example or link for me please?

Answer (score 0):

Derive all your activities from a single class (something like `ActivityBase`) that, in turn derives from system-provided `Activity`. Then implement `onRestart()` in `ActivityBase`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it your application that is restarting from scratch? Or just your activities that are restarting/resuming?

The Application class has an onCreate() method, and you can extend Application in your app to override its behavior. Just remember to change the name of the application in AndroidManifest.xml so it picks up your custom Application class when starting. This code would run before any activities start up. But it won't run every time an activity is stopped and restarted. If that's what you need, this won't do it.

You could also implement a singleton class that contains an initialize() method, or restart() method. You simply call it from onRestart() in each activity you want it in. It sounds like this special code ought to be localized away from your activities so I don't think I'd recommend extending Activity to put the code there.

Comment: well what I'm trying to do is to make it so when the user "closes" the app and then re opens it they are presented with a log in screen. and the way I got the log in screen working is that onrestart it starts the "login" activity for restult. the activity does the password checking and then closes with a result okay if they authencated correctly. and if it closes with an result canceled it throws them out of the program. it seems to work well just wanted to save copy pasting that everythere.